# Using If or Case (or any other method) to increment a value based on country code

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table built like this, which assigns a unique articleId starting with zero for each user.

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `artcId` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `artcUserId` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `artcStackId` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `artcTitle` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`artcUserId`, `artcId`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

There also is a part which assigns a running serial number (artcStackId) to each article. You'll see in the code.

Thing is, is it somehow possible to assign a artcStackId based on the country of the user? That country code will come from php.

Eg: If it's US then start from 10001+1, if its UK start from 20001+1, if its CA then start from 30001+1 and on & on.

Will it be possible to do this?

My current SQL query goes as follows:

```
insert into articles (artcUserId, artcStackId, artcCountry, artcTitle)
select 4,IFNULL((MAX(artcStackId)+1) ,0),'US','Hello World'
FROM articles;
```

But the way I want it it'll have to go like (this is just an example sql):

```
insert into articles (artcUserId, artcStackId, artcCountry, artcTitle)
select 4, IF artcCountry = 'US' then (selct MAX(artcStackId)+1
                                      where artcCountry = 'US'),
       'US','Hello World'
FROM articles;
```

I hope you get the idea.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a TRIGGER:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_articles
BEFORE INSERT ON articles
FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.artcStackId=coalesce(
    (select max(artcStackId)
    from articles
    where artcCountry = new.artcCountry)+1,1)
;
```

or something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_articles
BEFORE INSERT ON articles
FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.artcStackId=coalesce(
    (select max(artcStackId)
    from articles
    where artcCountry = new.artcCountry)+1,

    case when new.artcCountry = 'US' then 10001
         when new.artcCountry = 'UK' then 20001
         when new.artcCountry = 'CA' then 30001
    end)
;
```

[see it working here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da57d/1). Then you can insert without specifying the column artcStackId, since it will automatically be calculated.

Comment: Your answer does exactly what I had in mind. But, like the other poster said, do u see this running into problems like duplicate values during a heavy load or any other problems?

Comment: @Norman if you insert more than 1000 records for each country, you will run into problems with duplicates, so maybe it's better to have a column with the ID of the country (1,2,3,...) and a coulmn with the count, starting from 1. Also, this might be a little slow. I think that using a trigger the table is locked, so there shouldn't be concurrency problems and the same max() can't be assigned to two different rows - but i need to confirm you this

Answer (score 0):

Technically this will work, but you might run into problems with duplicate values for `artcStackId` during heavy load.  It's also not likely very efficient.

```
INSERT INTO articles (artcUserId,artcStackId,artcCountry,artcTitle) 
SELECT 4,MAX(artcStackId)+1,'US','Hello World' 
FROM articles
WHERE artcCountry = 'US' LIMIT 1
```

Also, this assumes that the articles table already has at least one row for that country.

A better option might be to have a `country` table with a `nextStackId` value on it.  In a transaction, update the next stack id in that table, select the updated value, use that for your insert, then commit the transaction.  That should be much safer.

Answer (score 0):

What happen if you create a new table named Cities, with the idCity and numberBeg as fields, and with a relation you will know from which number your begin to count